# Create an external component to a Openfire

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, tigase, apache-vysper

I want to create a XMPP Server for 3 features:

1. Whenever any client connects to the server, the server send a message to the client.
2. The server can publish a message to the client (publish/subscribe architecture).
3. A client can send a message to the server.

I did some research and decided to use a Openfire server and Strophe.js for my client. Since I want my server to have custom logic, I would have to create my own external component using Java. Could you guys suggest some documentation or tutorial for creating my own external component and also I hope my approach is correct. Apart from using Openfire I also found out about Tigase, but it seems it has some compatibility issues with Strophe.js. Do you think Apache Vysper could be used for the above 3 features.

Comment: You are asking at least two questions here:
1. How can I do X with Openfire?, 
2. Can I use Vysper to do X?
The answer to the second question is "yes", but doesn't fit well into this post about Openfire. Suggestion: Post a separate question or go to the developers mailing list for Vysper (dev@mina.apache.org)

Comment: anybody got the solution to question 1?

Answer (score 0):

I will just address your question as it relates to Openfire.  Asking what we think about other servers will get your question closed as being off topic for this site.

1. This can be accomplished with a plugin instead of a component.  The [Message of the Day](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp) plugin might already provide what you want.
2. This is vague.  Publish to all clients?  Based on what.  There is already a broadcast plugin if you simply want to send a message to all users (same link).
3. This is standard XMPP, which any server will support.